# redefine theorem to be tcolorbox

Tags: tcolorbox, thmtools

I have a large document with theoreme-like environments based on `\declaretheorem` and references  to them using `\label` and `\cref`.

**I want to redefine those theorem-environments to be colored boxes based on `tcolorbox`.**

Is there a simple solution without modifying the hole document?

Thank you very much.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,ngerman]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{thmtools}

\newtheoremstyle{break}{0pt}{0pt}{\normalfont}{0pt}{\bfseries}{}{\newline}{\thmname{#1} \thmnumber{#2} \quad \thmnote{\normalfont#3}}
\declaretheorem[style=break,name=Theorem]{theorem}

%% a colored Theorem style
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{theorems}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\newtcbtheorem[
number within=chapter,
crefname={Theorem}{Theoreme},
]{theoremTCB}{My Theorem}%
{colback=green!5,colframe=green!35!black,fonttitle=\bfseries}{th}

%% want to replace 'theorem' to be the colored 'theoremTCB'
%% what to do with \label  ?
%\renewenvironment{theorem}[args][default]{begdef}{enddef}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Intro}
\begin{theorem}[Optional title]
\label{myfirstTheorem}
    blabla
\end{theorem}
this is the ref: -- \cref{myfirstTheorem} --. 

The Theorem shell be redefined to look like:

\begin{theoremTCB}{Hey}{marker}
    hello
\end{theoremTCB}
this is the ref: -- \cref{th:marker} --. 

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`amsthm` and `tcbtheorem` cannot be used interchangeably, that means that your best shot to replace the one with the other is to use your editor's search and replace functionality (or `sed` or other nifty tricks in `vim` or `emacs`).

One thing you can do without changing our document, is using the skinning mechanism with `\tcolorboxenvironment`:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,ngerman]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{thmtools}

\newtheoremstyle{break}{0pt}{0pt}{\normalfont}{0pt}{\bfseries}{}{\newline}{\thmname{#1} \thmnumber{#2} \quad \thmnote{\normalfont#3}}
\declaretheorem[style=break,name=Theorem]{theorem}

%% a colored Theorem style
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{theorems}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\newtcbtheorem[
number within=chapter,
crefname={Theorem}{Theoreme},
]{theoremTCB}{My Theorem}%
{colback=green!5,colframe=green!35!black,fonttitle=\bfseries}{th}

\tcolorboxenvironment{theorem}{ 
    breakable,
    colback=green!5,
    colframe={green!35!black},
}

%% want to replace 'theorem' to be the colored 'theoremTCB'
%% what to do with \label  ?
%\renewenvironment{theorem}[args][default]{begdef}{enddef}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Intro}
\begin{theorem}[Optional title]
\label{myfirstTheorem}
    blabla
\end{theorem}
this is the ref: -- \cref{myfirstTheorem} --. 

The Theorem shell be redefined to look like:

\begin{theoremTCB}{Hey}{marker}
    hello
\end{theoremTCB}
this is the ref: -- \cref{th:marker} --. 

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @Tobias - You could make the border on top larger and change the color of the text to make it look more like `theoremTCB`, but right now I don't have the time to do it (also, I think it looks cleaner the way it is).

Comment: Thank you very much for your competent answer! It helps me a lot to know what is possible and what you would recommend.